# Build arg from Bitbucket Pipeline not showing up in final image

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

In my pipeline file I have the following...

```yaml
pipelines:
  tags:
    '*.*.*-dev':
      - step:
          name: Build Base Image
          script:
            - echo ${DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD} | docker login --username "$DOCKERHUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin
            - docker pull ${IMAGE_NAME}:base
            - docker build . --file base.Dockerfile --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:base --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:base-${BITBUCKET_TAG} --cache-from ${IMAGE_NAME}:base
            - docker push "${IMAGE_NAME}:base"
            - docker push "${IMAGE_NAME}:base-${BITBUCKET_TAG}"
          services:
            - docker
      - step:
          name: Build Final Image
          script:
            - echo ${DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD} | docker login --username "$DOCKERHUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin
            - docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:${BITBUCKET_TAG} --build-arg IMAGE_NAME="${IMAGE_NAME}:base-${BITBUCKET_TAG}" --build-arg BITBUCKET_TAG="${BITBUCKET_TAG}"
            - docker push "${IMAGE_NAME}:latest"
            - docker push "${IMAGE_NAME}:${BITBUCKET_TAG}"
          services:
            - docker
```

And in the dockerfile...

```
ARG IMAGE_NAME
ARG BITBUCKET_TAG
FROM $IMAGE_NAME

...other build stuff

ENV API_REV_VERSION=${BITBUCKET_TAG}
```

For reference, IMAGE_NAME seems to work just fine in the image, (but only with the syntax above).

However, even though I can confirm that BITBUCKET_TAG is not empty, because it only runs when it's not, the environment variable shows up as null in the final image.  (Running `env` in shell shows `API_REV_VERSION=` on its own line)

Why would the env variable not get set properly?